# Should i upload files one by one or at once?

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit2, multipartform-data

Actually I'm uploading files into `node.js` server by `mulitpart/form-data` with the help of `retrofit2` . And these things are running fine . But what I'm asking is **should i upload multiple files at once or run a loop and upload them one by one ?**

Any suggestions or advise are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let retrofit deal with it for you, you can pass a list of files to be uploaded and Retrofit will take care of it:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> sendManyFiles(
@Part("content") RequestBody content,
@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

To create a MultipartBody with a file, use:

```
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), 
            file
        );
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, file.getName(), requestFile);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir actully currently I'm doing this but my question is which approach is more efficient  **all file at once** or **one by one**

Comment: I'd say let retrofit manage the dispatching of multiple files (all files at once), if you're going to implement the dispatching yourself you'd add an extra layer of abstraction that is unecessary, which is already done by the library and which is probably more efficient then the way you would do (no doubting you capacity as a programmer, but retrofit has been built by many people).

Comment: You'd need to manage possible erros for example which is already done in the lib.

Comment: Thanks again for your enlightenment sir . You've cleared all my doubts.